# React component not detecting change in redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I'm doing a chat service.

[image]

Everything is working fine, expect the following functionality :

- when a new message comes, I want the chatroom list (on the left side) to be updated. The chatroom of the new message should move to the first position. However, the component doesn't detect the change automatically. I need to click on the list to have it updated.

To do so, I tried the following reducer :

```js
case NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE:
      const setRoomFirst = (array, roomId) => {
        const chatIndex = array.findIndex((arr) => arr._id === roomId);
        array.push(...array.splice(0, chatIndex));
        return { arr: array, hasBeenUpdated: chatIndex !== -1 };
      };

      const rooms = state.rooms;

      // move room to first position
      const updatedRooms = setRoomFirst(rooms, action.payload.message.chatRoom);

      if (updatedRooms.hasBeenUpdated) {
        // will always be the first room
        updatedRooms.arr[0].messages.push(action.payload.message);
      }

      return { ...state, rooms: updatedRooms.arr };
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

The component that will manage the state of the chat :

```js
function Chat() {
  const classes = useStyle();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const callback = useCallback(
    (rooms) => {
      console.log("dispatch");
      dispatch(newChatMessage(rooms));
    },
    [dispatch]
  );

  const { roomId } = useParams();
  const rooms = useSelector(ChatRoomsSelector);

  const [selectedRoom, setSelectedRoom] = useState(
    roomId || (rooms.length ? rooms[0]._id : null)
  );

  const oldRoomsValue = usePrevious(rooms);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("rooms has changed", rooms);
    if (!selectedRoom) {
      setSelectedRoom(roomId || (rooms.length ? rooms[0]._id : null));
    }
    if (oldRoomsValue !== rooms) {
      console.log("a change in rooms has been detected");
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [rooms]);

  const onSelect = useCallback((roomId) => {
    setSelectedRoom(roomId);
  }, []);

  const current = rooms.filter((room) => room._id === selectedRoom)[0];

  return (
    <Container>
      <Typography variant="h1" className={classes.title}>
        Messagerie
      </Typography>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <ChatListContainer
            rooms={rooms}
            roomSelected={selectedRoom}
            onSelect={onSelect}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={8}>
          {current && <ChatContentContainer room={current} />}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Chat;
```

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the redux state and you did not indicate you are using immer so that's something you should not do:

```
case NEW_CHAT_MESSAGE:
  const {
    payload: { message },
  } = action;
  //find or create room
  const room = state.rooms.find(
    (room) => room._id === message.chatRoom
  ) || { _id: message.chatRoom, messages: [] };
  //add message to room
  const roomWithMessage = {
    ...room,
    messages: [...room.messages, message],
  };
  return {
    ...state,
    //set room as first in rooms
    rooms: [
      //room with message is the first
      roomWithMessage,
      //other rooms without the room with message
      ...state.rooms.filter(
        (room) => room._id !== roomWithMessage._id
      ),
    ],
  };
```

Your effect has missing dependencies, this can cause some problem when you want the effect to run and I found some other inconsistancies (see comments in code):

```
function Chat() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // your code does not show how you need to use this
  //  if this is to dispatch a new chatmessage then the
  //  paremeter passed would not be rooms but message {chatRoom:roomid, ...other}
  // const callback = useCallback(
  //   (rooms) => {
  //     console.log('dispatch');
  //     dispatch(newChatMessage(rooms));
  //   },
  //   [dispatch]
  // );

  const { roomId } = useParams();
  const rooms = useSelector(ChatRoomsSelector);

  const [selectedRoom, setSelectedRoom] = useState(
    //use optional chaining for cleaner syntax:
    //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining
    roomId || rooms?.[0]?._id
  );
  //use Array.prototype.find if you want to find one item
  const current = rooms.find(
    (room) => room._id === selectedRoom
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    //a console.log does not show what you want to do here
    //  the only thing you actually did is change selectedRoom
    //  when current room changes and no selectedRoom was provided
    setSelectedRoom(selectedRoom=>selectedRoom || current?._id);
  }, [current]);

  const onSelect = useCallback((roomId) => {
    setSelectedRoom(roomId);
  }, []);

  return 'jsx';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much [HMR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1641941/hmr) for your answer !
I would give you a hug if I had a chance. ^^

Just one thing to correct : I needed to enumerate the result of filter in the reducer to make it work.

```js
return {
        ...state,
        // set room as first in rooms
        rooms: [
          // room with message is the first
          roomWithMessage,
          // other rooms without the room with message
          ...state.rooms.filter((room) => room._id !== roomWithMessage._id),
        ],
      };
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to spread the state.rooms.filter array, updated the answer. Good to hear it helped